# Change css clas in SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: css, sharepoint, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reporting-services-2012

I want to format class in SQL SSRS, which name is `sqlrv-WaitControlBackground`.

I want to center, and upper position:

[image]

I managed to create in Sharepoint CSS and add class `sqlrv-WaitControlBackground` with properties:

[image]

```
.sqlrv-WaitControlBackground{
      margin: auto;
      width: 30%;
 }
```

But it's not working well. I want to increase the position on top, but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have my own stylesheet - from sharepoint I add to link: &rc:Stylesheet=myStyle

I use it because parameters area is too wide:

```
.ParametersFrame
{
    background-color:#FFFFFF;   
    border: 0px solid #a4b7d8;
    width: 830px;
}
```

Style of Wait control is overrided by anothed classes - you can view this in DOM Explorer (IE F12), but you could make this setting important like this:

```
.WaitControlBackground
{
    cursor: wait;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #ebf3ff;
    border: 1px solid #a4b7d8;
    left: 300px !important; 
}
```

I hope this will help!